# Why does the parent of my button get highlighted when my button is clicked on in mobile chrome?

Tags: html, css

I have this issue where the parent of a button or an element with a click event attached to it is highlighted when clicked on in mobile chrome browser. This happens even if the parent does not have a click event attached to it. I was not trying to implement highlight on click in mobile browsers but trying to adjust the default highlight implemented by the browser.

[image: Entire parent highlights when button is clicked]

I have looked at the definition of this feature on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) and it says that the webkit-highlight indicates which element you're tapping on but in my case, the entire parent was being highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that this was happening because I had set `cursor: pointer` on the parent div. I had thought this was purely changing the shape of the icon and does not have any other purpose but it appears to have its side-effects. It also does not say otherwise on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).